# How to upgrade from Neo4J 2.0.4 to 3.3.3?

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to upgrade from Neo4J 2.0.4 to 3.3.3 and I followed all the procedures as outlined on the single-instance upgrade page:
http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.3/upgrade/deployment-upgrading/

I imported all the configs using the `2.x-config-migrator.jar` utility and then ran `neo4j-admin import` to import the database from 2.0.4 into the 3.3.3, which seems to have worked.

However, when I try to start neo4j with the new database (running `neo4j console` to see errors as the normal `neo4j start` didn't work) I see the following error message after this:

`2018-02-18 22:59:53.328+0000 INFO  Starting upgrade of database`

`2018-02-18 22:59:53.335+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@4ae9cfc1' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Not possible to upgrade a store with version 'v0.A.1' to current store version`v0.A.8`(Neo4j 3.3.3).`

I tried researching for this problem, but there's absolutely no info. The upgrade path 2.0.x(latest) to 3.3.2 is supported, so I guess it's the same for 3.3.3 as it's only a minor upgrade.

When I remove the imported database `graph.db` from the `data` folder and just try to run `neo4j console` on a freshly installed database I also get this error:

`2018-02-18 23:09:31.440+0000 ERROR The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
2018-02-18 23:09:31.440+0000 WARN  unavailable The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.`

However, when I install a clean database through Neo4J Desktop it runs fine.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.12.6 and Java 1.8.

How could I try to resolve this problem?

Comment: You might want to upgrade first to the latest 2.3 version (2.3.12 I think), then upon successful upgrade there, upgrade to 3.3.3.

Comment: Yes but the upgrade says the path 2.0.x is supported. Plus to upgrade to 2.3.x I'd have to go through several steps and I don't really know what they did on the way to the data structure to ensure that it is supported... I don't know why nobody from Neo4J can answer this. It's a kind of problem that any user may have...

Comment: Given what you encountered, I'd wager 2.0.x isn't actually supported. I'll ask around and see if this is known (and requires a documentation update), or a bug to be handled. In any case, upgrading from the latest patch on the 2.3.x line is much more likely to work. Remember 2.0.4 was released in 2014...we really don't see many people running versions this old.

Comment: @InverseFalcon so you don't think it's my local issue or any Java-related stuff?

Comment: @InverseFalcon you were right it worked, but no so smoothly. see the answer below. i'll post it to the issues on neo4j github.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I have to answer this question myself as I spent several hours sorting this out.

First of all, Neo4J claims they support the upgrade path from the latest 2.x release to 3.x but this is not true. I had the version 2.0.4 (which is the latest 2.0 release and there were numerous problems migrating the settings and the old database into the new structure. It would simply not start.

I had to first upgrade to the latest stable 2.x version of Neo4J, which is 2.3.8. I ran into some problems with settings (I used authentification in 2.0.4 but I had to use the newly built in authentication module that 2.3.x provides, so I had to change some settings and remove the auth plugin). You also need to upgrade the database storage from 2.0.x to 2.3.x (by uncommenting the setting in conf).

Once you install and check that 2.3.8 is running and that your old database works, you need to then download the latest 3.x release.

However, the settings migration tool doesn't work properly. It creates numerous settings which are not supported by the new version, so you have to move them manually or not move them at all. Besides, the migration tool doesn't run under Java 1.7 so you might have to install Java 1.8 for the migration tool to even launch... So don't use it.

After that's done, provided you already upgraded your DB to the latest 2.x release, you can run the neo4j-admin import tool to import that DB into the new 3.x version and to convert it.

The whole process is described in detail here: https://github.com/noduslabs/infranodus/wiki/Upgrading-Your-Neo4J-Database-from-2.x-to-3.x